# How to derive covariant derivative and Lie derivative of tensors

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

1) As title says, how does one derive the following
equation for covariant derivate of tensor:
$A^{\alpha}{}_{;\beta} = A^{\alpha}{}_{,\beta} +
\Gamma^{\alpha} {}_{\gamma\beta}A^\gamma$
where $\Gamma^{\alpha}{}_{\beta\gamma} \,$ is
a Christoffel symbol of the second kind; and Lie
derivative of tensor from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_calculus#Differentiation ?

And I am having a hard time grapsing what
Christoffel of second kind would "symbolize". Can
anyone explain this in this derivative context?

Edit: now I understand what and how to derive covariant derivative of tensors, so it's fine to explain lie derivative of tensors only.

Comment: What definition of "covariant derivative" are you using? There are a few (equivalent) ones out there.  The way one would derive that formula would depend on your initial definition.

Comment: As used in the link.

Comment: It looks as though the Wikipedia article _defines_ the covariant derivative by that formula, no?

Comment: You say ``I am having a hard time grasping what Christoffel of second kind would `symbolize.' "  What notion of a connection are you using?  Providing this would make any explanation easier.

Comment: I now just want lie derivative part. You can just skip explanation on Christoffel sysmbols.